# How to Configure Spring MVC 4 to send and receive soap messages in two way SSL using Web Service Consumer?

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc, ssl, cxf, soap-client

I have tried to configure Spring MVC in two way SSL using Spring Ws to connect to third party but due to the lack of documentation I have decided to integrate my Spring MVC 4 Application with Web Service Consumer .I am a beginner in Web Service consumption.I would like to know **how to configure my Spring MVC 4 application with web service consumer with annotation based configuration to achieve a Two way SSl communication with Third party and also encrypt my soap messages before it is sent to the https server ?If any links or sample code would be helpful**.
Also if the WSDL is located in a a https link how do I generate the classes?

Comment: are you going to use CXF?

Comment: @pedorfb Yes I would like to use Spring Mvc with CXF  to connect to the Bank Api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is huge. There is no a trivial solution

I can provide the steps and guide to the manual

**1)Resolve CXF dependencies to include libraries in your project**

Use maven, ivy or download. You need jax-ws and related
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/using-cxf-with-maven.html

**2) Generate a Java client with wsdl2java to your wsdl**

For example

```
wsdl2java -p com.mycompany.greeting Greeting.wsdl
```

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html

**3) Create the jax-ws programmatically**

wdsl2java have done the work for you
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/how-do-i-develop-a-client.html#HowdoIdevelopaclient?-JAX-WSProxy

```
HelloService service = new HelloService();
Hello helloClient = service.getHelloHttpPort();

String result = helloClient .sayHi("Joe");
```

Note: It is also possible configure with spring

**4) Configure the  authentication with client certificate**

This is the hard step
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport(includingSSLsupport)-ConfiguringSSLSupport

Define a conduit file with the reference to your certificate. This is an example

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:http-conf="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
    xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
           http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

   <http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit"> 
        <http-conf:tlsClientParameters disableCNCheck="true" secureSocketProtocol="TLS"> 
            <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="password" > 
                <sec:keyStore type="pkcs12" password="password" 
                    file="yourcertificate.p12" /> 
            </sec:keyManagers> </http-conf:tlsClientParameters> 
            <http-conf:client Connection="Keep-Alive" MaxRetransmits="1" AllowChunking="false" /> 
        </http-conf:conduit>
</beans>
```

If you prefer to do programmaticaly you can do

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(helloClient);
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
//set the parameters in a similar way to file
```